# Binding a class to another class's Property

Tags: c#, architecture, parameters, properties

The title may sound a little strange, so I'll try to explain my problem:

Lets say I have a class that holds some Information:

```
class InfoHolder
{
  public int MyInfo1 {get; set;}
  public int MyInfo2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have another class, that does something with an info:

```
class InfoGUIRepresenter
{
  // Display an int in some kind of GUI
  // Allow the user to change the int via the GUI
}
```

Now I would need two objects of the representer class, to expose my Info-class to the user: One representer for each of the two infos. To achieve that it would be nice to pass each of the properties as some kind of "parameter" to my representer classes.
But of course that's not possible in C#. Another solution would be to pass the names of the properties and then use reflection to access them - not very nice!

Is there any solution to this? Maybe some kind of architecture that addresses this kind problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to pass two delegates - one for the setter and one for the getter:

```
var holder = new InfoHolder();

var representer = new InfoGUIRepresenter(() => holder.MyInfo1,
                                         value => holder.MyInfo1 = value);
```

Then your `InfoGUIRepresenter` constructor would take a `Func<int>` and an `Action<int>`. (Or you could make the representer generic, for different types of property.)

Answer (score 0):

You mention display "in some kind of GUI" which implies you are using a GUI framework.  Surely that framework supports a well defined model for this sort of situation.  Eg MVVM if you are using WPF (your info objects are models, your UI is a view and you can do binding from view to model via view model properties bound to UI element properties).  I.e are you not trying to reinventing the wheel here?

Comment: Actually the GUI framework is written by myself. It's basically some Rectangles drawn on a GDI Canvas. So it doesn't support ANYTHING (at least for now) ;-)

Comment: Ok fair enough - I guess you have some reason for going that route - but sounds like quite a bit of hardwork and maintanance ahead of you though.